# How do I load cached Image from only pressing the button Once

Tags: swift, swiftui, nscache

I have a problem that I can't seem to resolve, am fairly new to swift programming I don't understand what is happening, why is my cached image loading only when I press the button twice instead of once

```
@State var openCameraRoll = false
@State private var imageSelected = UIImage()
@State private var showImagePicker = false
@State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
let imageCache = ImageCache.shared

Button(action: {

    openCameraRoll = true
    ImageCache.shared.checkIfImageExistsInCache(forKey: "ProfileImage")
    imageCache.set(imageSelected, forKey: "ProfileImage")
}) {
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.get(forKey: "ProfileImage") {
            Image(uiImage: cachedImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .padding([.top, .leading], 70)
                )
                .overlay(
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                        .foregroundStyle(.red, .white)
                        .padding([.top, .leading], 70)
                        .font(.system(size: 23))
                )
                .onAppear {
                    print(cachedImage)
                }
    }
    else {
        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .padding([.top, .leading], 70)
            )
            .overlay(
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red, .white)
                    .padding([.top, .leading], 70)
                    .font(.system(size: 23))
            )
    }
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
    ImagePicker(selectedImage: $imageSelected, sourceType: sourceType)
}
.actionSheet(isPresented: $openCameraRoll) {
    ActionSheet(
        title: Text("Choose Source"),
        buttons: [
            .default(Text("Library")) {
                sourceType = .photoLibrary
                showImagePicker = true
            },
            .default(Text("Camera")) {
                sourceType = .camera
                showImagePicker = true
            },
            .cancel()
        ]
    )
}
```

```
class ImageCache {
    static let shared = ImageCache()
    
    private init() {}
    
    func set(_ image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        // Convert the image to data
        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            // Save the image data to UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: key)
        }
    }
    func get(forKey key: String) -> UIImage? {
        // Retrieve the image data from UserDefaults
        if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key),
           let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
    func delete(forKey key: String) {
            // Remove the image data from UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
}
```

here's the link to the video, sorry but I wasn't able to get it below 2mb thanks [text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oah24CB60zdk2zZGvdkSQR1D-V_siKyb/view?usp=sharing)

I tried a function that refreshes the app once the image is placed but that didn't work

Comment: What is `ImageCache.shared.checkIfImageExistsInCache`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove that its a function to check if the image was cached  ...                                                                                                      func checkIfImageExistsInCache(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        // Check if the image data exists in UserDefaults
        return UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) != nil
    }

Comment: You shouldn’t do work such as checking if an image is in cache in the body of a View, do that somewhere else that is stable and doesn’t get redrawn all the time and example is a “Config” model

Comment: Also you shouldn’t save images into UserDefaults, they are meant for small things.

Comment: is there a better way kindly ? cause I want to avoid coredata as much as possible or any form of database, I want the image to be saved in cache

Comment: I removed the checking function...I was using it in the testing phase since the image wasn't showing up

Comment: Any other way is better. Just search for image cache on google. Staying away from databases isn’t quite rational if you need storage. UserDefaults is meant for small things it is the most insecure/unstable type of storage.

Comment: This is what I got "Using UserDefaults for caching images, especially large ones, is not a good idea. UserDefaults is intended for storing small amounts of user data such as settings and preferences, and it's not designed for efficient and performant storage and retrieval of large binary data like images".....thanks I think I'll just use CoreData or maybe Kingfisher library